# Probability density estimation with Dirichlet process

Tags: density-function, dirichlet-process

I'm trying to estimate a joint probability density function in a quite high dimensional space (around 15 or even more).

I've heard about Dirichlet process methods to do this kind of things. Do you know a good paper/phd thesis/book to learn about this ?

Thank You for your help

Comment: A good starting point (not that it is easy) is the book: [Bayesian Nonparametrics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Nonparametrics-Cambridge-Statistical-Probabilistic-Mathematics/dp/0521513464). In particular Ch. 2 and Ch. 3. A more technical book is [Bayesian nonparametrics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Bayesian-Nonparametrics-Springer-Statistics-Ghosh/dp/0387955372/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1390903418&sr=1-6&keywords=bayesian+nonparametrics) (different book, same title).

Comment: The Dirichlet Process is used in density estimation when you have reason to believe the target density is a mixture of some unknown number of component distributions. If that's not the case in your problem, the Dirichlet process is probably the wrong tool.